# Database Design for a cosmetic e-commerce brand

Tags: database-design

I am developing an e-commerce store which has cosmetic products. Now the challenge I am facing is that seller has a set of nail polish/ lipsticks boxes etc and those items inside can be sold individually as a single product.
There is no issue creating a single product table and put everything there but I don't want seller to keep adding same type of product over and over again which just differs in color shade.
I tried to group them by creating a product table having product name, category, brand and putting individual products inside as a product_variants table which has price, sku, attributes and everything but that made a lot of confusion even for me as I am calling for variants and showing them as individual product on main site, even on admin panel when looking at product list, actual products are inside of product list shown.
My question is How can I make this simpler for me and for seller also.
Is there any other way for simplifying this kind of relationship or should I just create a parent table/group and link back all products to them for easy read.
Thanks

Comment: I think an important thing to consider is the language and how the business treats the products when selling them. Is there one lipstick that comes in multiple options (multiple colors)? Would a user look up the lipstick, then select a color on the product page? Or would they all be presented as separate colors? Then, consider how closely the internal admin page resembles the customer-facing website.

Comment: Context:: I've worked at a few different retail companies, and the data model is always either (1) closely modeled based on the way products are presented to the user, and admin tools also basked on how it's presented to the user, or (2) a "boat anchor" of pain where the data model is used for historical reasons, despite being painful to use now. The "best" data model will be based on knowledge of the user experience. Adding UX detail to your question will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Some people do actually consider products of a different color as two separate products and store them with two different unique identifiers (such as `SKU`s) in their `Products` table. But if your business rules considers two products of different colors as the same product by `SKU` then you can have a separate `Dimensions` table with attributes about the `Product` such as color, size etc.

Based on the example schema you provided, it seems like you're trying to *squeeze* all the attributes into the `ProductName` which is a *denormalized* way to store that data. Rather you should split the attributes out to separate columns (even if you store those columns in your `Products` table itself). For example, you can have a `ProductName` column that repeats the name `Some Fancy Nail Polish` and have a column for `Color` with values like `Red`, `Green` etc and even another column called `Shade` with values for `Shade-01`, `Shade-02` etc, and of course the `SKU` column to uniquely distinguish between each `Product`.

Structuring the data into relevant columns like this helps *normalize* how you store your data and makes it easier to maintain and even utilize throughout your application. When you display it in the application, you have more control and granularity to show the data across separate fields, and to do things such as have the user select from the distinct list of `ProductName`s (smaller list than the number of records in the `Products` table) and then showing only a smaller subset of the `Products` that share that `ProductName`.

This is a basic implementation to explain the concept, but if your database has to catalog other products besides nail polish, then you'll want to consider *normalizing* your table further, and perhaps have a table specific to nail polish products vs a table for wig products, etc, each with their own relevant columns. And you could still have a single `Products` parent table that essentially stores the `SKU` and any generic columns applicable to all product types.

Comment: SKU will be different for each one. Only hurdle is how to make it easy to add, read, view in admin panel.

Comment: Normally an e-store would have the application dealing with that, not just an admin panel.

Comment: @MysticalSam Not sure I follow why it wouldn't be easy? If you do end up storing each unique `SKU` in your `Products` table, you could at least simplify it in the Admin Portal by making them select a "product" from a distinct list of the product names as the first step in funneling the data down, then showing them just the `SKU`s of that product name.

Comment: Let's put it this way. I want to group the similar kind of items in admin panel so that they can be added with ease in db and view with ease.

Comment: Let's assume a I have a box of cosmetic products and I want them to add to website.
`tbl_products
----------------
id | product_name           | category
1  | Some Fancy Nail Polish | Nail Polish
2  | Branded Lipstick       | Lipsticks

tbl_product_variants
---------------------
id | product_id | product_variant_name   | product_variant_sku | product_variant_price
1  | 1          | Matt Red Shade-01      | SKU-1               | 10
2  | 1          | Matt Green Shade-03    | SKU-2               | 8
.
.
12 | 1          | Glossy Yellow Shade-03 | SKU-1               | 10
`

Comment: Now Whole product will be called `Some Fancy Nail Polish Matt Red Shade-01` and `Some Fancy Nail Polish Matt Green Shade-03`

Doing repetions of same thing, addding same category and name again and again of same box is bit much so I used this approch but it is not the best way to understand what is product and why website is displaying variants as products. Need something else for main `tbl_products` table. May be call it `tbl_parent_products` or `tbl_product_group`

Comment: @MysticalSam Your example would be great to add to your original post. Comments are not meant for extended discussions or details like this. But please see my updated answer that essentially addresses your example. If you have any further questions, feel free to comment with them, but any details specific to your example or question should continue to be added to your original post so it gets better attention.

Comment: Please refer to this link, this is basically how I want things to be on frontend. If you click on any color share, the image, name and sku changes.
`https://www.nykaa.com/maybelline-new-york-color-sensational-creamy-matte-lipsticks/p/353926?productId=353926&pps=2&skuId=1384680`

Comment: @MysticalSam I understand, and they probably store the data in their database in a normalized form like my updated answer suggests. And then they either have a View or in the application (website) code are concatenating the `ProductName` with the other attributes such as `Color` in this case when displaying it in the webpage. Pretty easy to do based on the database design I suggested.